# Eclipse debug and JBOSS deployment

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am debugging a web service project in Eclipse which is deployed on a local server as an EAR file using JBOSS. I want to know how the code that I debug and the deployed application are related. What I do not understand is though the debugger goes through the code that we see, it is actually executing the deployed application.